# Powershell Split with : but only once

Tags: powershell, split

So, here's a text file that contains content exactly like this:

```
DBSnapshotIdentifier : rds:xyz-new-2015-08-17-03-43
DBSnapshotIdentifier : xyz-new-2015-08-17-04-43
DBSnapshotIdentifier : rds:abc-2015-08-17-03-43
```

My code:

```
foreach($line in $lines)
{
$del = $line -split ':' | Select-Object -Last 1
}
```

I am trying to read the entire string (left of :), it's reading the entire string in 2nd content. But it fails for 1 and 3. For 1 and 3, the read value is xyz-new-2015-08-17-03-43 and abc-2015-08-17-03-43 respectively (note that rds:) is also omitted.

So, I want to get the entire string after first :, even if multiple :'s are found in that string. I tried -Unique with that, but no luck. Also tried -Last 2, but it is coming as 2 single words. I need the exact string rds:blah_blah_blah

Can someone please help me on this.?

Comment: @PetSerAl: Checked. but I am getting entire value of $del as DBSnapshotIdentifier   rds:xyz-new-2015-08-17-03-43

I just need rds:xyz-new-2015-08-17-03-43. Is this possible?

Comment: Just select second element `($line -split ':',2)[1]`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Awesome... Thanks :)

Comment: You could remove everything before the first colon with `$line -replace '^(.*?):` (which trades "what are the magic numbers ,2)[1] intended to do" for "what's the regex intended to do")

Answer (score 2):

why not?

```
"DBSnapshotIdentifier : rds:xyz-new-2015-08-17-03-43" -split "DBSnapshotIdentifier : "
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the line

```
$del = $line -split ':' | Select-Object -Last 1
```

to

```
$del = ($line -split ':' | Select -Skip 1) -Join ':'
```

This will effectively skip the first string in the array after the split. We then use the -join operator to rejoin the remaining parts.

Even though it hasn't been done above, I suggest you trim the final string.

You could also achieve this by changing the line to

```
$del = $line -split ':',2 | Select-Object -Last 1
```